# How can I change TextView text from adapter class?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to change text according to my `click listener` function. I used `findViewById` method to get `textview` and I use `setText` to change text of `textview` but in here I get an error which is *nullexception*. I am quite new at Kotlin with no Java experience. I did research about that I saw `Interface method` to change text I tried it but it wasn't work. How can I solve it?

Here my code which is from Adapter Class:

```
var dd = holder.customView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.toplamSayi)!!
dd.setText(tt)
```

Also I tried `dd.text = tt` but it wasn't work also.

**Edit:**

My Adapter Class:

```
private class DetailPageAdapterForSepetPage: RecyclerView.Adapter<DetailPageViewHolderForSepetPage>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DetailPageViewHolderForSepetPage {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
        val customDetailView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sepet_sayfasi_list_row_detail, parent,false)
        return DetailPageViewHolderForSepetPage(customDetailView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DetailPageViewHolderForSepetPage, position: Int) {
        var urunDb = sepetArr.get(position)

        holder.customView.urun_text.text = urunDb.eklenenUrun
        holder.customView.fiyat_text.text = urunDb.eklenenFiyat
        holder.customView.adet_text.text = "x" + urunDb.eklenenAdet

        var addedCount = urunDb.eklenenAdet.toInt()

        // ekleme butonu fonksiyonu
        holder.customView.imageButton4.setOnClickListener {
            addedCount += 1
            holder.customView.adet_text.text = "x$addedCount"

            // BURADA COUNT U BİR ARTTIRACAGIZ VE ARKADAN DIGER İKİLİ (URUN VE FIYAT) TUTAN ARRAYE DE EKLEME YAPACAGIZ.. YADA CIKARMASINI ASAGIDA..

            var urun = holder.customView.urun_text.text
            var fiyat = holder.customView.fiyat_text.text
            var adet = holder.customView.adet_text.text
            var addedData = SepeteGidenUrunlerModel(
                urunEklenen = urun.toString(),
                fiyatEklenen = fiyat.toString()
            )

            var fiyatStr = fiyat.toString()
            var droped = fiyatStr.dropLast(2)
            var doubleEklenecek = droped.toDouble()

            toplamTutar += doubleEklenecek
            var tt = toplamTutar.toString()

            holder.customView.toplamSayi.setText(tt)
            FirstDetailActivity.sepeteEklenenUrunler.add(addedData)
        }

        // cikarma butonu fonksiyonu
        holder.customView.imageButton5.setOnClickListener {

            if (addedCount > 1) {
                addedCount -= 1
                holder.customView.adet_text.text = "x$addedCount"

                var urun = holder.customView.urun_text.text
                var fiyat = holder.customView.fiyat_text.text

                var cikarilan = SepeteGidenUrunlerModel(
                    urunEklenen = urun.toString(),
                    fiyatEklenen = fiyat.toString()
                )

                FirstDetailActivity.sepeteEklenenUrunler.remove(cikarilan)

            }else if (addedCount == 1) {

                var urun = holder.customView.urun_text.text
                var fiyat = holder.customView.fiyat_text.text
                var adet = holder.customView.adet_text.text
                var cikarilan = SepeteGidenUrunlerModel(
                    urunEklenen = urun.toString(),
                    fiyatEklenen = fiyat.toString()
                )

                FirstDetailActivity.sepeteEklenenUrunler.remove(cikarilan)

                var sepetteData = SepetModel(
                    eklenenUrun = urun.toString(),
                    eklenenFiyat = fiyat.toString(),
                    eklenenAdet = adet.toString()
                )

                sepetArr.removeAt(position)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return sepetArr.size
    }
}

private class DetailPageViewHolderForSepetPage(val customView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(customView){
}
```

And XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SepetSayfasi">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/sepet_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toplamText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sepet_recycler_view" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topalmTutar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/toplamText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toplamText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textToplam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toplamText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toplamText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toplamSayi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textToplam"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textToplam" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: in kotlin no need to find id you can direct use like this holder.itemView.toplamSayi.setText(tt)

Comment: Can you post your Adapter class code and XML layout?

Comment: I did it but it is get error which is Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: @LucaPizzini I added now. I'm new at Kotlin. If you see any problem, I really need advices.

Comment: What is the type of `sepetArr`?

Comment: @LucaPizzini sepetArr hold my data with SepetModel which have 3 different string data.

Comment: In my code I assumed it was a `List`, change the parameter of `DetailPageAdapterForSepetPage ` accordingly.